# How to keep a chocolate fondue in a liquid form?

Tags: chocolate, fondue

I'm trying to make chocolate fondue for dessert to serve in a restaurant on Valentines Day. What should I do to prevent the chocolate fondue from burning during heating, and setting as it cools.

Comment: Fondue or fondant?

Comment: it's a fondue .
what should i do to prevent the fondue solidfication

Comment: @Doug - Do you think it's worth it to add back the information that this is for restaurant-scale use? The answers may not be as helpful if it's assumed that it's just for a couple to use at home.

Comment: I'm a young cooker in a restaurant actually . I'm trying to find out some solution for prevent fondue from solidification

Comment: Might have been slightly over zealous with the trimming. I have approved it by the way it's just not come through.

Answer (score 2):

You can either maintain the heat level through a heat source served with the food at the table or you can add a neutral-tasting oil to the chocolate mixture such as canola(rape seed) or vegetable oil.  Adding another fat will also help in preventing scorching of the chocolate.

Also the addition of some dairy to create a chocolate "sauce" can be a solution as well, but remember that fondue is about heating(and even cooking) food.  A cold bowl of chocolate, even if it is liquid at room temperature, probably isn't going to be as enjoyable for your guests.

Comment: So , it is possible if i maintain the heat level in a pot so it will be always ready to serve ? of course i will keep stirring it .

Comment: @KelseyLoyHangXiang, if it will be on a buffet you have a lot more flexibility.  You can simply have pure chocolate and as long as you keep stirring there won't be any problems if the heat is low enough or you could cycle the heat on and off.  The problem is if you do it like a traditional fondue where each table gets their own small bowl of the fondue sauce.

Comment: @Stephie, that's the cheap stuff... In the better establishments the chocolate sauce is quite hot and makes for a much more enjoyable experience when the marshmallows just start to melt and the biscotti get softer and the warm fruit releases different flavors...

Comment: @Stephie, that was my original thought too until I read the OPs latest comment. So I'm not sure.

Comment: Look at the original question, not the edited one.

Comment: My bad sorry. I forget we aren't all working in restaurants sometimes... :/